# .NET Core - Entity Framework - extra white spaces

Tags: entity-framework

I had extra white spaces added by EF when fetching data, so I changed NCHAR to NVARCHAR, but the problem still persists

**even after destroying the tables and recreating them**

I have read something about setting the table to fixed length or something but it was vague and had no code with it

anyone already hat these issues ?

how can I solve this once and for all ?

thanks

```
var partner = await _context.Partners
                    .Include(p => p.ModificationUser)
                    .Include(p => p.retributionPlan)
                    .Include(p => p.retributionPlan.ProductRetributionData)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);

var manager = await _context.Users.FindAsync(partner.Id);

if (partner == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}

var partnerFetch = new PartnerFetch();
partnerFetch.Manager = manager;
partnerFetch.Partner = partner;
return partnerFetch;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I replaced all the **nvarchar** by **varchar** in the sql schema